# WSARecvFrom hook: lpOverlapped not unique?

Tags: udp, hook, winsock, intercept

I've been trying to intercept UDP packets before they reach an applications logic. More precisely, that application is using a DirectPlay Server and there is no source.
So I found out that DirectPlay uses async IO by posting multiple WSARecvFrom, then having some workerthreads waiting with WaitForSingleObject and finally retrieving IO status with WSAGetOverlappedResult.

When WSARecvFrom returns, lpBuffers is not filled with data yet of course, because the operation is still pending and will complete later.

So my idea to get to the data was to save the lpOverlapped/lpBuffers pair in a std::map for every WSARecvFrom call and then, if an IO operation completes (in WSAGetOverlappedResult), I would get to the corresponding (now filled) lpBuffers by looking up the lpOverlapped in the map.

However, there seems to be a big problem: DirectPlay calls WSARecvFrom multiple times with the same lpOverlapped address sometimes, and even with the same lpOverlapped->hEvent or lpBuffers addresses, also for the same socket (none of these operations complete at this time, so they are all pending). I cannot understand why this happens, the doc clearly says:  "If multiple I/O operations are simultaneously outstanding, each must reference a separate WSAOVERLAPPED structure."
Because of this I cannot correctly retrieve the lpBuffers, because when WSAGetOverlappedResult is called, I don't know to which WSARecvFrom the lpOverlapped corresponds because there were several WSARecvFroms called, each with the same lpOverlapped! How can this be? Does anyone know how DirectPlay handles this? Could there be another way intercepting (and eventually dropping) UDP Packets? (I don't want to use drivers)

(There is a good reason why I'm trying to do this: Someone is sending exploited UDP packets to a gameserver using DirectPlay, and it "confuses" the DirectPlay logic, basically shutting down the server. So I have to filter out specific UDP packets before they even reach DirectPlay)

Happy for any hint!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure that the packets mess up DirectPlay and not the game server logic? I think it may be easier to hook a server packet dispatcher if possible, because you don't have to worry about the networking stuff. What about "lpCompletionRoutine" - is it set? Maybe you could hook there.

Comment: Yep, I'm sure. One specific UDP packet sent to DirectPlay and a DPN_MSGID_TERMINATE_SESSION occurs. Sadly, it is exploitable that easy... so I need a winsock hook, but why the hell is the same lpOverlapped used for multiple pending WSARecvFroms? This makes no sense... a completion routine is not used.

Comment: Hmm.. that is just weird.  I understood that the _OVL struct was used to queue up the I/O requests to the driver and so, yes, that would require a different _OVL for each I/O request issued.  I assume that you have locked up the accesses to the std::map?

Comment: Yep, locked, but I only logged the WSARecvFrom parameters now to see how dpnet calls it. I found out that it is actually IDirectPlay8Client::EnumHosts causing the duplicate calls (the server uses a local dummy client/player, don't know why). On server startup, 6x 12 WSARecvFrom is called, 6 different sockets, all values unique. Everything fine so far. But then, a client is created too and after EnumHosts(), 48x WSARecvFrom is called, on one new socket, but every 12 calls it uses the same parameters again, so it's 4x same lpOverlapped within these 48 calls and also lpBuffers->buf is 4x same...

Comment: I'm using a workaround now which seems to work well: Collect the sockets WSARecvFrom is called with in a std::set in the time between Server::Host and Client::EnumHosts. Then, at subsequent calls to WSARecvFrom, I can ignore any sockets that are not in the set (i.e. not being used by IDirectPlay8Server (as already said, duplicate lpOverlapped seems to occur only for sockets used by IDirectPlay8Client)).